# How to pass Java variable into HTML tag?

Tags: java, html, url, button

I have a variable which include a url.

```
String url = getEnvironment().getProperty(CUSTOMER_SIGN_IN_PAGE_URL);
```

So that how can i use this url variable as the url of  of following code segment

```
String customerMessage = new StringBuilder("Hi, We have received your request. Your account will be unblocked within 48 hours.")
     .append("<br><br><a href=\" url \" target=\"_blank\"><button> CONTINUE </button></a>")
     .toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your string with a second " and concatenate it with +

e.g.

```
     String customerMessage = new StringBuilder("Hi, We have received your request. Your account will be unblocked within 48 hours.")
            .append("<br><br><a href=\""+ url +"\" target=\"_blank\"><button> CONTINUE </button></a>")
            .toString();
```

In fact you should take a look on Java Server Pages (JSP) or Java Server Faces (JSF) if you want to implement a server based solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `String.format()`:

```
   String customerMessage = String.format("Hi, We have received your request. Your account will be unblocked within 48 hours.\n<br><br><a href=\"%s\" target=\"_blank\"><button> CONTINUE </button></a>", url);
```